# Can I use VBA to show the content of a Query folder in the Query CommandBars?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm already able to open the query pane using the command

> Application.CommandBars("Workbook Queries").Visible = True

Now I'm looking for a way to **open a specific folder** (in the pane) that contains some of my queries **and close all others**, still with VBA.

I tried the followed commande :

> Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("QueriesPaneFolderMyFolder")

assuming that "MyFolder" is the name of folder target in the Queries pane

it's not working, the process seams wrongly called.